# Is it possible to run a strategy in pine script version 5 as if it was in replay mode?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wrote a custom indicator script that returns different values if it's run in replay mode than if it's just applied to a static chart. This is because of my use of the barstate.islast condition. I need this condition for my script. I changed the indicator to a strategy and it's using the values I get when I apply the script to a static chart, but I need the values from a chart in replay mode, where there is a new "last" bar as each bar is added. Is there a way to run the strategy in replay mode?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In replay mode, `barstate.islast` returns `false` for every bar formed before the playhead. Once the execution of the script reaches the playhead, `barstate.islast` returns `true` for every following bar.

In normal mode, `barstate.islast` returns `false` for every bar formed before the real-time bar. Once the execution of the script reaches the real-time bar, `barstate.islast` returns `true` for every following bar.

If I understand correctly, you want your `if` condition to evaluate `true` in the following cases:

1. In **replay mode**: on every single bar that forms at/after the playhead
2. In **normal mode**: on every single bar that forms at/after the real-time bar

If that is the case, changing your if condition to `barstate.islast or barstate.isrealtime` should give you the desired behaviour.

`barstate.isrealtime` behaves similarly in normal mode to how `barstate.islast` behaves in replay mode. Its value is `true` on every bar following the rightmost (real-time) bar (including the real-time bar).

Here is some code you can test further with:

```js
//@version=5
indicator("barStates", overlay = true)

tick() =>
    varip int barTicks = 0
    varip int barTicksResetAtBarIndex = -1
    if bar_index > barTicksResetAtBarIndex
        barTicks := 0
        barTicksResetAtBarIndex := bar_index

    barTicks := barTicks + 1

int barTicks = tick()

if barstate.islast or barstate.isrealtime
    log.info("bar_index={0} (tick {1}), last={2}, confirmed={3}, lastconfirmedhistory={4}, history={5}, realtime={6}, new={7}", 
      bar_index, barTicks, barstate.islast, barstate.isconfirmed, barstate.islastconfirmedhistory, barstate.ishistory, barstate.isrealtime, barstate.isnew
      )

plot(bar_index, "bar_index", display = display.data_window + display.status_line)
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your detailed reply! Because tradingview runs the script on every bar in the price history, I was hoping I could get the strategy to return true for barstate.islast, sequentially, on every bar in the chart as if I had started a replay on the first bar and manually clicked forward. I tried barstate.isrealtime and it gives me the same result. After scouring every pine script source I can find, I don't think there is a solution. The script will always look at the chart as a whole and return true for barstate.islast for only one bar. Thanks again!

Comment: I realize I could do backtesting manually, or just leave a chart up and running in real time, but that's very slow and tedious. I'm going to see if it's possible to get the script to behave the way I want it without barstate.islast.